# Canvas resizing without performance loss

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, easeljs

I've made an app using HTML5 and everything is in a CANVAS tag.

The canvas is 1024x768 pixels. And leaving it like that it will get 60 FPS (webgl enabled).

However, to make it fit on every phone I added the following to my code:

```
$('#canvas').css('width','100%');
$('#canvas').css('height','100%');
```

It does work. The whole canvas and all of its children are resized and maintain their relative position.

The problem is that it makes my app very slow. I easily lose 20 FPS because of this. How can I do this the right way?

Comment: You could try wrapping the canvas in a div with width and height at 100%, getting the width and height of its parent div on document ready and resize, and setting the canvas's width and height to the same pixel value. If it's the percentages that are slowing things down, that should solve the problem.

Comment: @Kylok : percentage is evaluated once when set.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting the canvases width and height properties. Changing the width and height in CSS doesn't change the number of pixels in the canvas it only stretches the canvas.

So doing something like

```
//Compute the correct width and height somewhere.
$("#canvas").attr("width", computedWidth);
$("#canvas").attr("height", computedLength);
```

May give you better performance and it should make your game look better.